# how can tmpfs larger than SHMALL parameter?

Tags: linux, redhat, tmpfs

**The amount of Shared memory being utilized**:

`#> df -h /dev/shm
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                 125G   96G   30G  77% /dev/shm`

**The max amount of shared memory system-wide, set by the SHMALL kernel parameter**:

`ipcs -lm | grep shared
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 67108864`

**Question**: How is this possible? How can the max total shared memory be set to 64GB in the kernel, but `df` is reporting that 96G shared memory is being used?

Answer (score 0):

The `shmall` parameter refers to traditional UNIX IPC shared memory. You can see the memory allocations of that using the command `ipcs`. The `tmpfs` temporary filesystem is a totally different subsystem used as a ram based, swap backed filesystem.

`tmpfs` is used as the basis to perform posix shared memory in fact, which is a different type of shared memory system to unix IPC.

Comment: So basically,  other programs that use the POSIX API will show up as using space in tmpfs in addition to programs that use the IPC system?

Comment: And SHMALL is only governing total shared memory created using the IPC system?

Comment: Yes, the value does not dictate what tmpfs does.